# Ubuntu 20.04& 22.04 - Display signal lost when monitor switched off

Tags: display, hdmi

The problem is my Ubuntu box is connected to a TV. It used to wake up the screen whenever I changed to that HDMI channel. Recently it won't and I have to reboot to get the screen to come back. I don't know what has changed and I don't have the exact timeframe it started.
My googling mostly points to nvidia issues, which this can't be.

I'm using standard desktop version of ubuntu on an ASRock J4205 motherboard (Intel J4205 processor, Integrated intel HD Graphics 505). The system is plugged into my main tv to run Plex and a file server and has been running fine for years. TV is a modern Sony Android TV.
I was running Ubuntu 20.04 until this problem occurred, then I updated to 22.04 in the hope it would fix it.
I am using Cockpit to use the terminal to access the machine remotely. There is a keyboard attached and I have tried CTRL+ALT+F3/F2 with no result. Xrandr does not seem to work via terminal, it just says "unable to open display."

My skills are limited to following instructions, and I don't know where to start!

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, it can still be graphics drivers. I'm also using Intel Graphics on a NUC.